# SAS Return date 'number/order' per user

Tags: date, numbers, sas

I'm running the following query for a number of users, and

```
proc SQL;
  select 
  username, 
  (select min(sub.date) from sample sub where sub.username = outer.username)  Format=worddatx20.  as firstDate,
  date Format=worddatx20. AS betdate,
  monotonic() as numberOfDaysActive
  from sample as outer;
quit;
```

Monotonic() doesn't give the right value for numberOfDaysActive, as it just counts from the top of the rows returned regardless of user. For each user, I need to know when it is the users first day in the database, and a day count after that for each day the user is present.

Sample data as follows:

```
 INPUT username $ amount date5 : ddmmyy8.;
 DATALINES; 
 player1 90 12/11/08
 player1 100 04/11/08
 player2 120 07/11/08
 player1 50 05/11/08
 player1 30 05/11/08
 player1 20 05/11/08
 player2 10 09/11/08
 player2 35 15/11/08
 PROC PRINT; RUN;
```

What I want for the 'numberOfDaysActive' field is the following:

```
 player1 90 12/11/08 3
 player1 100 04/11/08 1
 player2 120 07/11/08 1
 player1 50 05/11/08 2
 player1 30 05/11/08 2
 player1 20 05/11/08 2 
 player2 10 09/11/08 2 
 player2 35 15/11/08 3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have records for every day?  Or do some users skip days?  Any chance you could add a bit of example data and example desired results?

Comment: Please make that an edit to the OP rather than a comment.  Put a colon (:) before DDMMYY6. to get it to input in that format.

Comment: Please edit your question again to add an example of exactly what you want to see, given the sample data you provided.  If you want to do what I **THINK** you want done, it's easier in a data step rather than SQL.

Comment: This can be done in pure SQL like this: Select username,
       select min(date) over (partition by username) as firstDate,
       date,
       row_number() over (partition by username order by date) as date_sequence
from data as outer; but SAS doesn't have the 'parition' or 'over' functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with SQL using SAS; SAS does not currently support windowing functions.  Here is a solution that involves sorting the data set and calculating your **numberOfDaysActive** variable as I think you want it:

```
data have;
   input username $ amount date5 : ddmmyy8.;
   format date5 ddmmyy8.;
   row_id + 1;
   datalines; 
player1 90 12/11/08
player1 100 04/11/08
player2 120 07/11/08
player1 50 05/11/08
player1 30 05/11/08
player1 20 05/11/08
player2 10 09/11/08
player2 35 15/11/08
run;

proc sort data=have;
   by username date5;
run;

data want;
   set have;
      by username date5;
   retain numberOfDaysActive;
   if first.username then numberOfDaysActive = 0;
   if first.date5 then numberOfDaysActive + 1;
run;

proc sort data=want;
   by row_id;
run;
```

Note I added a variable (row_id) used to preserve the original order of your data.  It's not clear that is needed but it is there just in case.  Also, my results do not exactly match you specified:  the last two rows have calculated values of **2** and **3** for **player2**.  If they really should have values of **1** as specified, I don't know how that was done.

Comment: That works fine, thanks. I don't need the original order, and you're right about the last two rows for player2! What if the date includes a timestamp, though? Will this 'if first.date5 then numberOfDaysActive + 1;' increment as a new day even though it's just another observation in the same day?

Comment: How can I add another variable to indicate whether the day was profitable for the customer i.e. add up the value of amount for each day and have it as an indicator variable beside numberOfDaysActive?

Comment: @user2146441 Please ask a new question and do **not** refer to this one.  Use my answer here as a model of how to ASK a SAS question: provide a sample data set (HAVE) and show the result you want (WANT).  Clear questions get good answers.